# wkhtmltoimage CSS3 gradient rendering in Snapshots

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I am using wkhtmltoimage to render a snapshot for my website which contains a background gradient but it doesn't show up in the generated snapshot.

I tried using on Ubuntu and Windows but am not able to find the error.

I even tried using the simplest command without any parameters.

```
wkhtmltoimage.exe <website_link> <image_name>
```

My original page looks same in all major browsers
Here is the screen print[image]

And here is the one generated by wkhtmltoimage
[image]

I am not sure what exactly is the problem. I tried looking at their existing issues as well but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Any change to get to that website; is it online? We could test with our installations.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check your gradient syntax. wkhtmltopdf uses the webkit syntax.

```
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgb(64,128,176)),color-stop(100%,rgb(1,73,129)));
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(64,128,176) 0%,rgb(1,73,129) 100%);
```

The second syntax will not count to wkhtmltopdf but the first one works for the version of wkhtmltopdf I have (0.10.0 rc2).

I also found that modern webkit syntax doesn't work. i.e. this didn't work

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccc 0%, #888 100%);
```

As per this : [stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565176/how-can-i-get-wkhtmltopdf-to-display-th-and-td-background-gradients)

Comment: It took me a while to get how the old format is for a radial gradient: `background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#fff 5%, #8dcae4 15%, #00a8d7 60%);`

Answer (score 2):

As as 0.12.2.1 of wkhtmltopdf the gradient css - either old or new doesn't work.

Comment: I'm observing the same. I get a gradient, but it's almost as if it's repeating and not in a way that's predictable.